# .htaccess redirect 301 with Get Parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, get

I want how to do a Redirect 301 when in the url have a get

```
www.example.com/test/locale.action?request_locale=ca to www.example.com
```

*request_locale=en and request_locale=es

I use this, but doesn't works

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /test/locale.action$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^request_locale=ca$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com/? [L,R=301]
```

Redirect to www.example.com?request_locale=ca

Comment: That should work. Clear your browser cache.

Comment: I clear cache, and nothing... the project is in Presta Shop, but normal redirects with urls without get works fine....

Comment: Move above rule just below `RewriteEngine On` and clear browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

```
The full code

<IfModule mod_security2.c>
   SecRuleRemoveById 207
   </IfModule>


## [GZIP] ##
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml

## [EXPIRES CACHING] ##
<IfModule mime_module>
    <files *.jpg>
        ForceType image/jpeg
    </files>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    <filesmatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|JPEG|JPG|gif|GIF|png|PNG|css|js|svg)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
        ExpiresActive on
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
    </filesmatch>
</IfModule>
## [/ EXPIRES CACHING] ##

# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule . - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]



#Domain: www.example.com
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]


# Images Blog

RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}modules/smartblog/images/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}modules/smartblog/images/$1$2.jpg [L]

# Images

RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]

# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]


#Domain: 
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]




# Images

RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]

# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|svg)$">
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404

# ~~end~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again

<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecRuleRemoveById 208
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
  SecRuleRemoveById 208
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecRuleRemoveById 210
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
  SecRuleRemoveById 210
</IfModule>

# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /castell_V1/locale.action$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^request_locale=ca$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com/? [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\.example\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]



    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/ajuda.action      http://www.example.com/content/36-ayuda
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/altresProductes.action    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/autentica.action      http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/avarcaNautica.action  http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallCarrito.action  http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/empresaProducte.action    http://www.example.com/content/14-la-familia
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/fetAMa.action     http://www.example.com/content/14-la-familia
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/fetDinsEspanya.action http://www.example.com/content/11-menorquinas-al-por-mayor
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/formulari_1.action    http://www.example.com/contactanos
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/identificar.action    http://www.example.com 
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/inici.action      http://www.example.com 
    # RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/locale.action?request_locale=ca http://www.example.com
    # RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/locale.action?request_locale=en http://www.example.com
    # RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/locale.action?request_locale=es http://www.example.com 
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/noticia_id.action?noticia=12  http://www.example.com/blog
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/noticia_id.action?noticia=13  http://www.example.com/blog
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/noticia_id.action?noticia=4   http://www.example.com/blog
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/noticia_id.action?noticia=9   http://www.example.com/blog
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/noticies.action   http://www.example.com/blog
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/origens.action    http://www.example.com/content/14-la-familia
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/outletCategoria.action    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/producteCategoria.action  http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/producteCategoria.action?categoria=1  http://www.example.com/609-menorquinas-hombre
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/producteCategoria.action?categoria=2  http://www.example.com/608-menorquinas-mujer
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/producteCategoria.action?categoria=3  http://www.example.com/610-menorquinas-nino
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/registrarClient.action            http://www.example.com 
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/representante_id.action?noticia=2 http://www.example.com/blog
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/representante_id.action?noticia=3 http://www.example.com/blog
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/representante_id.action?noticia=4 http://www.example.com/blog
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/representante_id.action?noticia=5 http://www.example.com/blog
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/representantes.action http://www.example.com/content/8-representantes
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/tendes.action     http://www.example.com/tiendas
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/trabajaConNosotros.action http://www.example.com/content/23-trabaja-con-nosotros
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=112    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=113    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=119    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=120    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=168    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=169    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=126    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=127    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=128    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=132    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=146    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=149    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=150    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=244    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=172    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=173    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=174    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=197    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=175    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=217    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=226    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=225    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=227    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=228    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=236    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=241    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=237    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=176    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=183    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=235    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=242    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=243    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=245    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=247    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=248    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=27     http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=287    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=291    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=297    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=298    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=301    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=32     http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=324    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=325    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=328    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=332    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=333    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=334    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=335    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=336    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=337    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=338    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=339    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=34     http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=340    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=341    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=349    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=35 http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=350    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=351    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=352    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=354    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=355    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=358    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=360    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=368    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=369    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=37 http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=375    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=377    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=379    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=384    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=385    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=387    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=388    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=389    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=39 http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=390    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=391    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=392    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=40 http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=402    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=403    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=404    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=412    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=415    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=42 http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=424    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=425    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=426    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=427    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=428    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=429    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=430    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=431    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=432    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=433    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=434    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=435    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=436    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=437    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=438    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=439    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=440    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=442    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=443    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=444    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=445    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=446    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=447    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=448    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=449    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=450    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=453    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=456    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=459    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=460    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=461    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=462    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=463    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=464    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=465    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=466    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=467    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=468    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=469    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=47 http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=470    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=481    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=482    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=483    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=486    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=490    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=494    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=495    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=496    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=498    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=499    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=502    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=507    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=508    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=51     http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=510    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=511    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=512    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=513    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=514    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=515    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=516    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=517    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=520    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=521    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=522    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=523    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=524    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=525    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=526    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=527    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=528    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=529    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=530    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=531    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=532    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=54 http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=543    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=547    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=548    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=549    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=55 http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=554    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=564    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=565    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=566    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=567    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=569    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=570    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=579    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=582    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=583    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=585    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=586    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=587    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=588    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=589    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=590    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=592    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=593    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=595    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=596    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=597    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=598    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=599    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=600    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=601    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=602    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=603    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=604    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=605    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=606    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=607    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=608    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=609    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=610    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=611    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=612    http://www.example.com
    RedirectMatch 301 /castell_V1/detallProducte.action?producte=614        
</IfModule>
```